# How to return the count of a column in the second table of the join along with other columns

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on a MySQL project that involves writing very complex MySQL queries. Now I have a problem trying to get the count of a specific column which value is not null of the second table in the LEFT JOIN.

This is my initial query:

```
SELECT  sr.id, 
        ta.id as ta_id
FROM survey_responses as sr 
LEFT JOIN
         (  SELECT id 
            FROM survey_responses 
            WHERE social_type_id = 3
         ) as ta ON ta.id = sr.id
```

I got the following result when I run it:

[image]

That is the expected result. That is fine. But now I am trying to add another column which returns the count of ta_id column that does not have null value along with other columns. So, I changed my queries to this.

```
SELECT sr.id, 
       ta.id as ta_id, 
       COUNT(ta.id) as ta_id_count 
FROM survey_responses as sr 
LEFT JOIN
         (   SELECT id 
             FROM survey_responses 
             WHERE social_type_id = 3
         ) as ta ON ta.id = sr.id
```

Now it is only returning one row as follow. The count is right, but other rows disappear:

[image]

How can I fix the query to also return other columns?

Comment: Your query is malformed. There are columns in the list of selected columns that neither are in a `GROUP BY` clause nor an argument to an aggregation function. Sadly instances of old MySQL versions or badly configured ones accept such erroneous queries. But the result can suddenly be funny.

Comment: see [mysql_only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: You need to add at the end of the query  `group by  sr.id,  ta_id `

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OVER() clause. This will allow a count without a GROUP BY. https://learnsql.com/blog/over-clause-mysql/

```
COUNT(ta.ID) OVER()
```

Kathi